# How to open the details of a single product using react-router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a Nav component, it has two links. The first link leads to the main page, and the second opens the Hat component. In turn, it sends a request to the server and receives an array of objects representing the list of products, when clicked, the page with the price of this product should open.[my cod](https://codesandbox.io/s/6l2ro1ro1k)

```
const Nav = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <NavLink to={"/"}>{"Foo"}</NavLink>
      <NavLink to={"/male/hat"}>{"hat"}</NavLink>
      <Switch>
        <Route path={"/"} exact render={() => <div>'100'</div>} />
        <Route path={"/male/:hat"} exact render={() => <Hat />} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
};

const Hat = () => {
  const [arrProd, setArrProd] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      await fetch(`https://foo0022.firebaseio.com//male/hat.json`)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(arr => setArrProd(Object.values(arr).flat()));
    })();
  }, []);
  console.log(arrProd);
  return (
    <Fragment>
      {arrProd.map(({ to, id, price, title }) => (
        <Fragment key={id}>
          <br />
          <NavLink to={`/male/hat/${to}`}>{title}</NavLink>
          <Route
            exact
            path={`/male/hat/${to}`}
            render={() => <div>{price}</div>}
          />
        </Fragment>
      ))}
    </Fragment>
  );
};
```

Comment: you can't use <Route /> outside of a router. The routes are not known to the router, which is why you aren't seeing anything rendered when u click one of the items.

Comment: @ Jameson This is not exactly what I wanted. I need the page to display information for only one product.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are using "exact" on the /male/hat route and clicking the product in the Hat component changes the route to something other than /male/hat, so Hat is no longer displayed. You have to show Hat because Hat is what shows the product price. If you remove exact, clicking the product will display the price of the product. Example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/y247880319?fontsize=14

Comment: @ Jameson Suppose I click on the first link, I expect that I will only see the price of the products and links Foo hat. I can not write this code but I can show in the [picture](https://cloud.mail.ru/public/4cuh/5KgKTve78)